# Meteor.setInterval on server side, Performance?

Tags: meteor

I was looking for a way to clean up some of the database entries I might not need after 24hours or something like that, I was looking into meteor code: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/832e6fe44f3635cae060415d6150c0105f2bf0f6/packages/oauth/pending_credentials.js

I found this part:

```
// Periodically clear old entries that were never retrieved
var _cleanStaleResults = function() {
  // Remove credentials older than 1 minute
  var timeCutoff = new Date();
  timeCutoff.setMinutes(timeCutoff.getMinutes() - 1);
  OAuth._pendingCredentials.remove({ createdAt: { $lt: timeCutoff } });
};
var _cleanupHandle = Meteor.setInterval(_cleanStaleResults, 60 * 1000);
```

I couldn't find any where the exectuion of the function. I was wondering if `var _cleanupHandle` means it will execute it every 60 seconds? and if it's it seems strange an endless function run every 60 seconds? It might be a general javascript question but I really trying to understand the performance of this kind of thing and if I can safely re use this technique? My main goal is to store temporary data on the server and remove it after it's not needed.

Comment: I know I am more than a year late here, but I am asking myself the same question. I plan on using setInterval to run a function to cleanup the DB. Did you end up using it ? If so, is it any good for this kind of jobs?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using a task queue library such as https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron.

For this approach, you would just specify your task and start it. You can also end the task whenever you want. Note that this is all server-side.

Adding a task

```
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Crunch some important numbers for the marketing department',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    // parser is a later.parse object. NOTE THAT THIS IS WHERE YOU SPECIFY THE FREQUENCY
    return parser.text('every 2 hours');
  },
  job: function() {
    var numbersCrunched = CrushSomeNumbers();
    return numbersCrunched;
  }
});
```

Starting the tasks

```
SyncedCron.start();
```

Stopping all tasks

```
SyncedCron.stop()
```

There are a lot more options so I recommend checking out the documentation.

Comment: I actually familiar with synced-cron and it's awesome package thanks. I was still trying to understand the base level of setInterval if it's really used like that and if it's possible. If it's that simple I would like to try to avoid any external package the code is for a package Do you have any ideas about the setInterval?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the implementation of the method: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/meteor/timers.js#L28. It's bound within a fiber so it's safe to use inside meteor -- as for performance, it's probably the best you'll get (much better than using native javascript timeout), unless you implement a more complex system with later.js (like synced-cron). Remember it all has to be bound within fibers if you want it to run smoothly within Meteor.